# How to Turn Off Line Numbers in Jupyter Notebook Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, formatting, numbers, jupyter

I tried using this code to turn off the lines:

```
IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = false;
```

And I also tried

IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = False;

But I get the following error: name 'IPython' is not defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution is to click on the 'Toggle Line Numbers' inside the View Tab of your Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

For **Jupyter 5.5.0** this also works perfectly.

<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>L</kbd>. It lets you to toggle the line number on and off. <kbd>L</kbd> can be small `l` or caps `L`.

Answer (score 1):

Esc and 'l' will remove the numbering from current cell.
Esc and 'L' will remove the numbering from all the cells of notebook.